# Proper tagged AST

Tags: haskell, monads, abstract-syntax-tree, gadt, name-binding

I’ve been trying to build tagged AST for a while now. Let’s introduce the issue:

```
data E a
  = V a
  | LitInt Int
  | LitBool Bool
  | FooIntBool (E a) (E a) -- er…
    deriving (Eq,Show)
```

The issue with that piece of code, to me, resides in `FooIntBool`. The idea is that it takes an *int* expression and a *bool* expression, and glues them together. But `E a` could be anything. This would be valid given the above definition of `E`:

```
FooIntBool (LitInt 3) (LitInt 0)
```

You can see the issue. Then, what do we want? A tagged expression. This is not possible given the current definition of E, so let’s introduce some *GADTs*:

```
data E :: * -> * -> * where
  V          :: a -> E l a
  LitInt     :: Int -> E Int a
  LitBool    :: Bool -> E Bool a
  FooIntBool :: E Int a -> E Bool a -> E (Int,Bool) a
```

This is quite nice! I can now right that kind of code:

```
FooIntBool (V "x") (LitBool False)
```

The issue with that is when I want to make it a monad, or an applicative. It’s just impossible. Consider the monad implementation:

```
instance Monad (E l) where
  return = V
```

That was obvious and straight-forward. Let’s see the bind implementation:

```
  V x >>= f = f x -- obvious as well
  LitInt a >>= _ = LitInt a -- obvious yeah
  LitBool a >>= _ = LitBool a -- …
  FooIntBool a b >>= f = FooIntBool (a >>= ?) (b >>= ?) -- AH?
```

We can’t write `a >>= f` and `b >>= f` since `f :: a -> E l b`. I haven’t found a solution to that issue yet, and I’m really curious how to deal with that and still being able to use de Bruijn indices (through *bound*).

Comment: It is not clear what your AST means, so it is also not clear what the Monad instance should be. I'd write an evaluator first, to get the semantics right, and then try to write the Monad instance.

Comment: It constructs a new value of a new type by gluing an `Int` and a `Bool`.

Comment: What I don't understand is the meaning of the second parameter of your GADT: for `V`, it seems to be the variable name type, but this type is lost in the definition of `FooIntBool` in the specific case of your example.

Comment: Indeed, sorry. Fixed. @didierc, it’s the variable name, yes. I tried to use something like `FooIntBool :: Int -> Bool -> E (Int,Bool) a`, but of course it doesn’t work if I want to fetch the `Int` or `Bool` from a `V`.

Comment: Well, yes there was this problem too. I am still confused by the meaning of each parameter of the gadt.

Comment: Yeah, it’s now a clear I have a design issue.

Comment: Using higher order tagged bound is a bit tough. I know Edward has done it a few times, but it might be worth using simpler methods than bound until you nail down some other design criteria.

Comment: @phaazon, it's not clear at all, you might want to implement a simple language which only acount for `Int`, `Bool`, and pairs of these, and it would be perfectly fine for some applications. Sorry if I sounded harsh, I merely wanted to know what is your intent. Besides, @JAbrahamson is right when he speaks about simpler methods: do it step by step.

Comment: Why do you suddenly grow an extra type parameter when moving from ADTs to GADTs? The `a` in `E x a` seems to indicate that all `V` subterms are labeled with a value of type `a`, which strikes me as a strange invariant to care about. I would expect just one type argument, and for the `a` in `E a` to indicate that you can evaluate the expression to produce a value of type `a`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, thanks! I was wondering what it meant, and your comment made me realise that it allows `E` to expose the type of index used for variables. Quite interesting!

Comment: @DanielWagner, yeah, `a` is a name.

Answer (score 4):

I think your typed AST is unlikely to work the way you want. The fact that variables are untyped is going to hurt. Try to imagine what it would be like to write an interpreter with an environment; you'd have to look up variables in the environment and than either cast the results into the correct types or fail with an error. So I'm going to suggest a slightly different AST with typed variables, and an as yet unexplained reordering of the type parameters.

```
data E v a where
  V          :: v a -> E v a
  LitInt     :: Int  -> E v Int
  LitBool    :: Bool -> E v Bool
  FooIntBool :: E v Int -> E v Bool -> E v (Int, Bool)
```

Now, as far as I know it is not possible to define a law-abiding `Monad` instance for this. Note that the kind of `E` is `(* -> *) -> * -> *`; it may be more intuitive for our purposes to think of it as `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)`. This is superficially compatible with what `Monad` expects, `* -> *`, at least if you partially apply `E` to some `v`, but then the types get weird. I believe you are already aware of this, which is why you had put your variable type parameter last; the intended effect of this is that `(>>=)` will represent substitution. However, if we did that with this new type I've proposed, it's not compatible with `Monad` at all.

There is a different kind of monad that can work, though. We can generalize its kind from `* -> *` to `(k -> *) -> (k -> *)` (where `k` in this case is just `*`). Note again that I've used parentheses to emphasize that, just like most instances of `Monad`, `E` is to be treated as a *unary* type constructor. We'll be working with natural transformations instead of just any old Haskell function:

```
type a ~> b = forall x. a x -> b x
```

(By the way, the kind of `(~>)` is `(k -> *) -> (k -> *) -> *`.)

To construct our new `HMonad` type class, we can just copy `Monad` and replace `(->)` with `(~>)`. There is one complication, which is that we have to flip the argument ordering of `(>>=)`, to make the types work out:

```
class HMonad m where
  hreturn ::  a ~> m a
  hbind   :: (a ~> m b) -> (m a ~> m b)
```

I'll just show you the `HMonad` instance for `E` and then attempt to explain it:

```
instance HMonad E where
  hreturn = V
  hbind f e = case e of
    V v            -> f v
    LitInt x       -> LitInt x
    LitBool x      -> LitBool x
    FooIntBool a b -> FooIntBool (hbind f a) (hbind f b)
```

Actually, this looks exactly the way a `Monad` instance would for an untyped version of the AST. Note that, as expected, `hreturn` just injects a variable, and `hbind` performs a kind of type-safe substitution by seeking out variables and applying the function to them. This works due to the higher rank types.

You can't quite do this with the bound package, since it uses `Monad` instead of this fancier `HMonad`. It is possible (and has even been done on multiple occasions) to write a version of bound that works for typed ASTs like this, but it's not clear whether it's actually worth it.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want, it is possible to write a well typed `Monad` instance. I haven't checked if it follows the monad laws.

```
instance Monad (E l) where 
  return = V 

  V x >>= f = f x 
  LitInt a >>= _ = LitInt a 
  LitBool a >>= _ = LitBool a
  FooIntBool a b >>= f = FooIntBool (a >>= q.f) (b >>= r.f) where 

    q :: E (Int, Bool) t -> E Int t
    q (V x) = V x 
    q (FooIntBool x _) = x

    r :: E (Int, Bool) t -> E Bool t
    r (V x) = V x 
    r (FooIntBool _ x) = x
```

Comment: The Applicative is determined by the monad, though.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I completely forgot about that.